# Java String.charAt() throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, error-handling, concatenation

The following code should give me a String concatenated from all characters after a space in a sentence:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateFromSentence("Hello World!"));

    }
    public static String generateFromSentence(String sentence) {
        String output = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(0));
        for (int i = 0; i <= sentence.length(); i++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' '){
                String following = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(i+1));
                output = output.concat(following);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Sadly it throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
        at Main.generateFromSentence(Main.java:9)
        at Main.main(Main.java:3)
```

I don't understand why the index would be out of range, at
`String output = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(0));`
I specify Index 0 - should be the first character of my string, right?
Thanks already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not in line `String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(0));` but in line `if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ')`. The reason is your for loop stoping condition. You must use `i < sentence.length()` instead of `i <= sentence.length()` as follows:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateFromSentence("Hello World!"));

    }

    public static String generateFromSentence(String sentence) {
        String output = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(0));
        for (int i = 0; i <= sentence.length(); i++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' '){
                String following = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(i+1));
                output = output.concat(following);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that indexes start at 0, so you can't iterate over a List or Array starting at 0 up to and including the List or Array size.

Additionally, keep in mind that for the same reason your (and my) code above will fail if the sentence is `"Hello World! "` (mind the   at the end of the sentence). The reason is the line `String following = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(i+1));`. To get around this issue you need to add a condition to your if statement:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateFromSentence("Hello World! "));

    }

    public static String generateFromSentence(String sentence) {
        String output = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ' && ((i + 1) < sentence.length())){
                String following = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(i+1));
                output = output.concat(following);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should also be i < sentence.length() in the first code bracket, right?